# Use jQuery to prevent click function of <a> element based on parent <li> element with class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent the default click action on a menu item in WordPress. I can add the class noclick to the menu item but the class is on the -li- element.

```
<li class="noclick"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
```

My first attempt was:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.noclick').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Then I realized I need to target the -a- element and I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it should just work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LI element has no default action when you click it, the anchor has

```
$('.noclick a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And wordpress uses noConflict mode as default, which means $ is undefined, so

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.noclick a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think that is accurate you can prevent the default action from a propagated handler also

Comment: The only problem I can see is that the code is not inside a dom ready handler.... or need to use event delegation

Comment: First, I feel foolish for forgetting the dom ready handler. Thanks @ Arun. That being said, I tried both '.noclick' and '.noclick a' and neither seems to be working. jQuery is loaded in the head and the script is loaded in the footer.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - True, in most cases jQuery will fix it if you prevent default on a parent element instead of the anchor, but it seems more appropriate to target the element that actually has the default behaviour one is trying to prevent.

Comment: @EdBooth - should work, the only reason it wouldn't would be that the element is either inserted later with javascript, or you have other errors. Did you open the console (F12) and check for any other errors.

Comment: @adeneo I took your advice and viewed the (F12) console. I am getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < which I've researched but I can't seem to find what is throwing the error.

Comment: @EdBooth - then you have a character out of place somewhere, doesn't the error give a line number or something ?

Comment: @adeneo - line 1. I just had a duh moment. Thank you for all your help. I was including the <script> in the external file and then enqueueing the script. I can't believe I did that.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is that your code is not inside [dom ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.noclick').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

The click event from the `a` element will get propagated to the `li` element so you can register a handler for the `li` element and then call `preventDefault()` in that mehtod

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.noclick a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

this will target `a` elements that are children of aelements with the class `noclick`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your scope is safe to use $ function like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   ...
});
```

then if you want to prevent the default click action on a specific menu item like that, you'd better try this:

```
$(".noclick>a[href*='http://google.com']")
```

or

```
$(".noclick a[href*='google.com']")
```

and then if you really want to prevent the all click actions then:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if($(".noclick>a[href*='http://google.com']").length>1){
        $(".noclick>a[href*='http://google.com']")[0].onclick = function(){
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        //it means there is something wrong with your query
    }
```

});

this will disable all actions even if those are disregarded if you do it using jQuery `e.preventDefault();`